# Detect valid method call using reagex

Tags: java, regex

```
    if (word.matches("^[a-zA-Z_](.)][a-zA-Z_]*$") ) {
          System.out.println(word);
    }
```

i need to write method to identify method callings within a class.
 eg. A a =new A();
    a.call();

i need to find the a.call() form my class.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. (copied from flag dialog)

Comment: This should work for your relatively simple example: `"^[a-zA-Z_]+\\.[a-zA-Z_]+\\(\\);$"`, but it won't find method calls that contain arguments, or cases where the object is the result of an expression. Those would be beyond what regex can handle on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `[a-zA-Z_]` matches only one character. Append `*` or `+` to match multiple characters.
- `.` matches any character. Escape `.` to match literal dot.

Try following regular expression:

```
"[a-zA-Z_]\\w*\\.[a-zA-Z_]\\w*\\(.*?\\)"
```

Example:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class T {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word = "A a =new A(); a.call();";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z_]\\w*\\.[a-zA-Z_]\\w*\\(.*?\\)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Chathuranga, You have to know that this code can't handle  `person.sayHello(other.getName())`. (Having multiple parentheses pairs)